# What is wrong with code snippets/blocks on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, markdown

I wasn't following Meta Stack Overflow too closely so maybe something was changed that I'm not aware of.
But each time I paste a snippet from a Python console I'm getting wrong formatting. What I'm doing wrong? It seems that `>>>` is confusing for Stack Overflow. I've tried to escape it with backslashes, and it was working fine in preview but doesn't work after the question is rendered.

I was able to observe that problem on: recent Chrome (Windows, Mac), Safari 4 (Mac).

Here is [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4259887/4) I wasn't able to make right.

Funny, I think the snippets are rendered just fine on Meta Stack Overflow.
Here is one:

```
>>> def throw(): raise Exception() 
... 
>>> a=1
>>> a=throw()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in throw
Exception
>>> a
1
```

Comment: Does this happen in stable/released/supported browsers? The team doesn't even look at bugs that only happen in beta/dev browsers.

Comment: @Popular it doesn't work on safari 4, mac os x.

Comment: @Popular Good point. I've forgot to mention that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a subtle case where the code-block was considered part of the bullet-list, so needed *double* indenting - otherwise it assumed the `>` was the markdown for a quoted section. I just added a new line between the "Check this out:" to break out of the bullet-list.

So with markdown:

```
- bullet 1
- bullet 2

    this looks like a code block, but isn't; it is just more text in bullet 2

- bullet 3
- bullet 4

        this *is* a code block in the bulletted list (in bullet 4)

finish bullet 4

this text is no longer part of the bullet-list

    and hence this is a code-block
```

and to prove it:

- bullet 1
- bullet 2

  this looks like a code block, but isn't; it is just more text in bullet 2
- bullet 3
- bullet 4

  ```
  this *is* a code block in the bulletted list (in bullet 4)
  ```

  finish bullet 4

this text is no longer part of the bullet-list

```
and hence this is a code-block
```

Comment: or you can add `<-- separator -->` if you need to disambiguate at the bottom of a list